# How to replace every other occurance of a string

Tags: r, stringr

How do I replace every other occurance of a string in R? I'd like to to replace all the `\q`'s with q tags `<q> </q>` but I'm having trouble replace every other occurance to get my tag right.

```r
library(stringr)

x = r"{I said \qHockey\q}"
str_replace_all(x, "\\\\q", "<q>") # not correct should have closing tag for 2nd occurrence


y = r"{I said \qHockey\q and \qBaseball\q}"
str_replace_all(y, "\\\\q", "<q>") # not correct should have closing tag for 2nd and 4th occurrence
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can capture values between `\\q` as a group.

```
library(stringr)

x = r"{I said \qHockey\q}"
y = r"{I said \qHockey\q and \qBaseball\q}"

str_replace_all(x, "\\\\q.*\\\\q", function(m) paste0('<q>', gsub('\\\\q', '', m), '</q>'))
#[1] "I said <q>Hockey</q>"

str_replace_all(y, "\\\\q.*?\\\\q", function(m) paste0('<q>', gsub('\\\\q', '', m), '</q>'))
#[1] "I said <q>Hockey</q> and <q>Baseball</q>"
```